# Can a Giant Frog move normally with a Swallowed enemy?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, movement

When a Giant Frog swallows an enemy, is it able to move normally as long as it is not over-encumbered?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes.

The rules regarding [giant frogs](https://open5e.com/monsters/miscellaneous-creatures/giant-frog.html) say:

> The frog makes one bite attack against a Small or smaller target it is grappling. If the attack hits, the target is swallowed, and the grapple ends.

The frog is no longer slowed down to half movement by the grappled creature (*Player's Handbook*, p195) once the creature is swallowed. So unless the creature's weight heavily encumbers the frog (if using the [encumbrance variant](https://open5e.com/gameplay-mechanics/ability-scores.html#variant-encumbrance)), it can move normally. Remember, however:

> The frog can have only one target swallowed at a time.

So it loses that option after it swallows a creature. Until the DM decides the target is no longer swallowed, anyway, likely via digestion.

Comment: By the quotes above, the giant frog swallows a target, not a creature, and can have one target swallowed at a time, not a creature. I realize that one cannot grapple an object, but a case could be made by the wording that a creature that becomes an object is still the same "target". Without this logic, a  Giant Frog could by RAW swallow 100 people in 1 sitting.

Comment: @keithcurtis true enough. That wasn't material to the question. I'll fix it.

Comment: A more... visceral answer. :)